# How to fix a Same-Origin-Policy violation in iframe contentWindow

Tags: javascript, iframe, websocket, same-origin-policy

I use APE and recently after updating chromium based browsers there was a communication failure with APE.
Cors policy blocks the loading iframe window. The code blocks at this point:
`iframe.addEvent('load', function() { if (!iframe.contentWindow.APE) setTimeout(iframe.onload, 100); else iframe.contentWindow.APE.init(config;) });`

The error is :
Failed to read a named property 'APE' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin 'address_page_with_other_port' from accessing a cross-origin frame.

how can this be circumvented without disabling security in the browser?

I tried to use postMessage but I can't replace this code so that it works. On Firefox it works after all and on web-security disabled on chrome.

Generally this is an APE (Ajax Push Engine) library that has worked for years until now, I can't change the library just need to fix the current one.

Comment: Look into [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for cross-origin messaging.

Comment: If your not already using HTTPS for your site, that would be the next thing to try.

Comment: Failing that I see that APE was last updated 9 years ago, it is probably time to migrate your code to something more modern.